# If a function has infinitely many discontinuous points, is this function guaranteed to be not Riemann integrable?

Tags: integration, analysis

I know that if the $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is bounded and have finitely many discontinuous points, $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

Then how about when $f$ has infinitely many discontinuous points?

I know, for example, the Dirichlet function on $[0,1]$ is not integrable since it contradicts the fact that if the function is Riemann integrable, then the Darboux upper sum should equal to Darboux lower sum. Also, the Dirichlet function does have infinitely many points in $[0,1]$. Can I say "since it has infinitely many discontinuous points, the Dirichlet functions is not integrable"?

Also, for $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x& x=\frac{1}{n}&n=1,2,3,...\\ \\
1 & \text{others}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Even though this function also has infinitely many discontinuous points, I suspect that,in fact, this function is integrable

I know nothing about the measure theory, but I did hear something like "if the set of discontinuous points has measure zero, then the function is integrable". If using this theorem, can I say that since the Dirichlet function's discontinuous points in a set with measure 1, it is not integrable; and for the second function, it seems that the measure of its discontinuous points is zero.

Anyway, since I only know very basic analysis, is there some explanation for this by not using measure theory or other advanced knowledge? Thanks

Comment: Obviously you mean "Riemann integrable", because the answer is trivial for Lebesgue integration. But you should make this explicit in your question.

Comment: A Riemann-integrable function can even have uncountably many points of discontinuity. A function is Riemann integrable if and only if it's bounded and and its set of points of discontinuity has Lebesgue measure zero. You can construct a bounded function showe set of points of discontinuity is the Cantor set.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function is Riemann integrable on any interval and the integral evaluates to 0 over any set. The Lebesgue criterion for integrability states that a bounded function is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of all discontinuities has measure zero. Every countable subset of the real numbers - such as the rational numbers - has measure zero, so the above discussion shows that Thomae's function is Riemann integrable on any interval. The function's integral is equal to 0 over any set because the function is equal to zero almost everywhere.